# Trying to hide null values from being printed

Tags: java, android-studio

How do I hide null values from being printed? I have one Products table which has 5 columns. ID, Dairy, Fruit, Vegetables, Grains, and Protein.
When I search for dairy it brings up null values. Whats the best way to hide it?

```
public String dbToStringDairy() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String dbStringDairy = "";
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)) != null) {
            dbStringDairy += " ";
            dbStringDairy += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PRODUCT_DAIRY));
            dbStringDairy += "\n";    
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    return dbStringDairy;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Simplest way to return something else instead of `null`, using an `if else` statement to check if the return result is `null` or not, if it is `null` store something else so that the program wont return and print `null`.

Here some simple example:

```
public String dbToStringDairy()
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String dbStringDairy = "";
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast())
        {
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID))!=null)
            {
                dbStringDairy += " ";
                dbStringDairy += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PRODUCT_DAIRY));
                dbStringDairy += "\n";

            }
          c.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();

        //Replace the `null` into other useful information
        if(dbStringDairy==null){
          dbStringDairy="No Results"; 
        }


        return dbStringDairy;
    }
```

There are a lot of way to ensure your program won't print out `null` value. This method perform in the dbToStringDairy(), there is also way to do it during your Print Implementation.

Anywhere, hope this simple solution could help.